# Debugging in Eclipse (Java); can't hover over a variable when breaking to view the value

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse to code Java (for Android) and I'm trying to debug the code as I normally do (i normally do C# though).

From what I can tell, debugging in Eclipse is really bad. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but it seems to be just awful.

This is the code that is being run, I get some sort of exception and I want to see what the Exception is, by breaking in the "catch"-clause and viewing the variable "e":

```
try
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService( Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    NetworkInfo.State state = mobNetInfo.getState();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.v("MyAp", e.toString()); // I break on this line, and want to see what e is
}
```

The problem is that I cannot see "e" by holding my mouse over it (as I can in my beloved Visual Studio).

Now, I know that I can bring up the tab "Variables" which lists all variables accessible from when I'm breaking, but that's not optimal.

Just so I know - Eclipse has no way of "hovering" over the variable you are interested in, as in Visual Studio?

### Edit

Thanks for the answers. However, still have the same problem =(

Comment: This seems like a rather strange question, but the answer is yes, it does. It'll pop up the value in a tool tip.

Comment: though i prefer other IDE, hovering while debugging should work with eclipse.

Comment: Be _CERTAIN_ that you have compiled with debug information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have to be in Debug view in order to hover over objects and see their properties.  At least that's how my copy of Eclipse 3.4 works.

Of course, you also need to be in Debug view to have the Step Into, Step Over, Continues, etc... buttons...

Comment: Debug view means what? I am indeed running the code "in debug"... What do you mean with "debug view"?

Comment: I am in "Debug Perspective" if that is what you mean =)

Comment: Yes, I meant Debug Perspective.  I can hover over objects when I'm in this view... although I did use a built in class to test it; `List<String>`... actually `ArrayList<String>`, but I wanted to test to make sure it worked if I declared the variable by its interface.

Comment: Ok, thx. I cannot hover and see values for some strange reason... hmm

Comment: Debug View is the tree panel that shows the running processes and their threads and stack frame, with the run, step into, step over, etc buttons. Debug Perspective is the collection of panels (Views) and their arrangement in the Eclipse window. You can open the Debug window in any perspective. Personally I only use one perspective with all the views in it that I use during debugging and editing. Eclipse switches to the Debug *View* automaticlly when it hits a breakpoint. By default also to the Debug Perpective, but I turned that off.

Answer (score 9):

Go to Preferences-> Java-> Editor-> Hovers  and tick the box 'Variable Values'. If you want Hover to happen automatically then leave the Key Modifier section blank.

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be bugs in Eclipse related to this:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317045
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330061
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=286237

So, yes it is *supposed* to work, but it doesn't always. I'm having this issues on some classes. It seems to be consistent which classes work and which don't, probably related to what jar the class is coming from etc, but I have no real clue as to what causes it. Would love to see some reproduction scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can also highlight the variable, right click, and choose to watch it. Then it shows up on the watch tab. You can also set automatic break points that trigger on the exception being thrown rather than at a particular line of code. There is <strike>not</strike> 'hover' option to view the variable as in Visual Studio in recent versions of Eclipse.

Comment: hovering over the variable will show the content while halted on a breakpoint

Comment: I stand corrected - was using an older version of Eclipse. It does indeed have the hover.

Comment: Weird, I will have to investigate that.

Comment: Jeremy corrected his answer, and someone chose to not remove the downvote. This is relevant and helpful, given older versions of Eclipse do not have this functionality. Upvoting to restore the balance.

Comment: there is a shortcut to Inspect the selected expression `Ctrl+Shift+I`. You can change variable values if you select for example `miVar=5` and hit those keys.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem a bit strange, but do you know that the code window has focus? I have observed that sometimes the appearance of the tooltip depends on whether a view has focus or not (which I guess is an SWT bug).

Comment: Yes, code window has focus, and I am in "Debug Perspective" (i can Step...)

Answer (score 1):

I have also found that in the "Debug" view (the tab with the little green bug as an icon) where it shows all the threads, Eclipse sometimes doesn't show the variable's values if the currently breakpointed thread isn't selected.

If anyone else runs across this problem, then you might have hit a breakpoint, but the currently running thread isn't the one highlighted in the "Debug" window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> `Hovers`, and click `Restore Defaults`.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, Goto: Preferences > Java > Editor > Hovers - Javadoc (click on it and remove the ctrl+shift keys from there), then it should work normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct answer is the @RogerThomas one.

Go to 'Window' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Java' -> 'Editor' -> 'Hovers'
Then check 'Variable Values'.

If the 'Variable Values' option collides with 'Combined Hover', uncheck last one or configure new keys for it.