# Eclipse version kepler does not show variable values on hover

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse kepler. I have a Java project and in debugging mode when I hover my mouse pointer on a variable it does not show me the value of that variable. I have tried setting Window -->Preferences -->Java --->Editor --->Hovers and checked combined hover and variables values. In variables values I have pressed CTRL for key modifier.

It's not working. could you please help me?

Comment: Hey, sometimes it happens that the variable you are trying to hover when on debugging mode is not accesible in the current scope. Make sure it is not the case (try with other variables?)

Comment: Have you tried to access the variable value in any other way like expressions / variables view? Do they work?

Comment: By the way: the hovers menu in the eclipse preferences you mentioned contains a restore defaults button. My first idea would be to try the reset.

Comment: @GrayCygnus : It's same with other variables too..

Comment: @Regan maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029533/debugging-in-eclipse-java-cant-hover-over-a-variable-when-breaking-to-view-t) question can help you...